# please expain wx.grid.Grid.create()

Tags: python, wxpython

can any one please expain me the functionality of this function

```
wx.grid.Grid.create()
```

i created a frame and inside that i create a grid using this function

every thing is fine but while closing that frame my whole application is closing

while closing i just need to distroy the frame only not the whole application

thankz in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the frame with the grid in it is the only top-level window, then closing it will close your application. If you close the only frame in any program, how would you open another? There's nothing left to click on.

---

Mike Driscoll

Blog:   http://blog.pythonlibrary.org

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `self.Destroy()`? If so, try `self.Close()` instead.

or bind `wx.EVT_CLOSE` to your custom close function

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseWindow)

def OnCloseWindow(self,event):
     //do anything here
```